# Automatic text breaking in \text{} doesn't work. Neither do newline now breakline, text is written into boundaries

Tags: line-breaking, german

%%English is not my main language, this might be a german problem but google didn't help here.The text in \text{} in written into the set boundary.It doesn't break into a new line and just disappears. Adding \newline or \linebreak doesn't break the text into a newline either. It's just ignored. Do I have options other than trying to rephrase? %%

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}  
\usepackage{ngerman}  
\usepackage[left=25mm,top=15mm,right=20mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage{lmodern}   
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}   
\usepackage{float}  
\usepackage{ulem}   
\usepackage{epstopdf}   
\usepackage{amssymb}   
\usepackage{listings}   
\usepackage{color}   
\usepackage{caption}   
\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}   
\usepackage{subfigure}    
\usepackage{colortbl}  
\usepackage{wrapfig}  
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  
\parindent 0pt    
\pagestyle{scrheadings}   
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  
\setlength{\headsep}{1.5cm}  
\lohead{ \today}  
\chead{}  
\rohead{}  
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  
\pagenumbering{arabic}  
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
\begin{document}  
    \pagenumbering{gobble}  
    \title{}  
    \pagenumbering{gobble}  
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}  
    \maketitle  
    \tableofcontents  
    \newpage  
    \pagenumbering{arabic}  
\subsection{Äquivalenz $\Leftrightarrow$}  
\text{Die Äquivalenz A$\Leftrightarrow$B von A \& B ist diejenige Aussage die genau dann wahr ist, wenn A und B beide wahr oder beide falsch sind.}  
\begin{table}[H]  
    \centering  
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} \hline  
    A & B & A$\Leftrightarrow$B \\\hline  
    w & w & w \\\hline  
    w & f & f \\\hline  
    f & w & f \\\hline  
    f & f & w \\\hline    
    \end{tabular}  
\end{table}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just remove the \text command as well as the set of {}. You may also want to replace the ngerman package with \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Could you please add an example of the output and the desired output? I for example access stack exchange from the phone.

Comment: `\text` beneath other things (which are about choosing font and fontsize) typesets its argument in "**restricted** horizontal mode" while automatic line-breaking is only in "(unrestricted) horizontal mode". You use  `\text` after a subsection-command, i.e., when TeX is in vertical mode. I.e. TeX goes from vertical mode to restricted horizontal mode. If you just omit `\text{`...`}`, then the character `D` of `Die Äquivalenz...` triggers TeX to switch to (unrestricted) horizontal mode where automatic line-breaking is done.

Comment: unrelated but you don't need to load epstopdf, inputenc  or color (epstopdf is normally automatically handled by graphicx, utf8 inputenc is the default, and color is already loaded by colortbl

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers! Deleting \text{} solved my problem.

Comment: @UlrichDiez: Can you write up an answer for this post?